# How to make 2 inputs fill remaining parent width with equal widths?

Tags: html, css

I want to style a div as a time input. I wrap 2 inputs with a div, and place another colon div in the middle.

I tried to set the inputs' flex-grow to be 1 so that they will grow at the same width. They do seem to be the same width, but they overflow their parent.

How can I make them same width but also fit their parent?

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="left">
  <div id="middle">:</div>
  <input type="text" id="right">
</div>
```

Comment: Add `input { min-width: 0 }` as by default inputs have a minimum width assigned.

Comment: can you provide a image of your desired output? (just a sketch)

Comment: @DulanJayawickrama, something like that: `[   :   ]`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="left">
  <div id="middle">:</div>
  <input type="text" id="right">
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

I simply added `width: 50%;` to the input fields so they take half of their parent width.